# Celery in dokku doesn't see sqlite records

Tags: python, django, sqlite, celery, dokku

My stack is: Django, Celery(Redis broker), Dokku.

My code put the record in sqlite database and put the task for Celery:

```
package = Package.objects.get(pk=package_id)
package.download_status = 'QUEUE' # package is Django ORM object
package.save()

task_download_package.delay(package.id)  # put a task to redis for celery
```

Now I need to get this object from sqlite database inside the Celery task. But inside the Celery task process I can't see the record:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_download_package(self,
                          package_id: int):
    try:
        package = Package.objects.get(pk=package_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print("Package with pk={} not found".format(package_id))  # I HAVE GOT THIS MESSAGE
        return
```

But when I ask package.download_status from Django process by my special endpoint I got "QUEUE" status.
It looks like Django and Celery processes has different containers or diffenrent databases.
I have checked connection.settings_dict['NAME'] and it's return the same "/app/db.sqlite3" value for Django and Celery processes.

This code without Dokku works fine, but now I need it with Dokku.
Why Celery doesn't see record in sqlite db?
Is it actually the same database? May be I need something like a Commit? (I use Django save method)
How I can fix it?

Comment: "It looks like Django and Celery processes has different containers or diffenrent databases"—that's very likely. I know it works that way on Heroku, which inspired Dokku. SQLite is a poor database choice for modern containerized hosting. Use a proper client-server database like PostgreSQL instead.

Comment: Do you use transactions to save data to your database?

Comment: No, I don't use transactions for sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by share db.sqlite3 file on common directory on Dokku host computer. And set the path in the application settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/my_user/my_company/my_app/database/db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

And share this directory for application container:

```
dokku storage:mount my_app /home/my_user/my_company/my_app/database/:/home/my_user/my_company/my_app/database/
```